# I want to retain values on a page after I print/cancelled the print window

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, printing

I have a small form that gets the input of a user on what is to show in a document. Then I have a preview button and a save button at the bottom. The preview button opens the print window to show the document. What i want is that after I print or cancelled the print preview, the values are still in the form. Can this be done? Here's my code.

**Javascript:**

```
function printFunc() {
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById('printDiv').innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
        window.close();
        return false;
    }

function getInfo(){
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                printFunc();
                document.getElementById("dummy").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("printDiv").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "try.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("title="+title);
    }
```

**Original Form:**

```
Title: <input type="text" id="title">
<div id="dummy"></div>
<input type="button" value="PREVIEW" onclick="getInfo()">
<input type="button" value="SAVE">
```

**AJAX request:**

```
<?php 
  $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
?>

<div id="printDiv">
  THE TITLE OF THE DOCUMENT IS <?php echo $title;?>
</div>
```

Comment: how is the data removed from the form? surly not by making an ajax call?  And that is not really a form, just saying.  What's this `document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;` all about? maybe removing your data?  why not copy it somewhere and hide it instead of overwriting it.

Comment: what i mean is that the textbox where I write the title resets after the print window is closed. what i want is that what I write in that textbox is still there even after the print closes. I can do something like another ajax call to overwrite the div of the original form, but isnt there a simpler way?

Comment: why/how does it get reset, that was my question.  How can we keep data we have no idea how it's rendered or removed to begin with.

Comment: Well, it seems that the page reloads after the print window is closed. I tried removing document.body.innerHTML = restorepage; but it broke the page. I think its this code that overwrites the textbox, but I can't seem to find a way to get around it.